# wifiphisher traceback. error after entering the number of AP

Tags: python, linux, exception, terminal, wifi

Recently, I used the wifi phisher tool in Kali Linux. when I enter the number of AP in the list, I get the following trace in the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wifiphisher.py", line 743, in <module>
    dhcp(dhcpconf, ap_iface)
  File "wifiphisher.py", line 407, in dhcp
    Popen(['ifconfig', mon_iface, 'mtu', '1400'], stdout=DN, stderr=DN)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your issues in [sophron github](https://github.com/sophron/wifiphisher/issues), so you can try this changes in your wifiphisher.py:
Change to python2 in the header code.

Change this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
```

or  while you running the program you must select the network manually:

```
-a MAC -c CHANAL -jI INTERFACE -aI INTERFACE
```

similar issues [here](https://github.com/sophron/wifiphisher/issues/3)

NOTE: My first time, I had a problem  with wifiphisher, so I fixed it updating  Kali Linux repositories and then upgrading softwares.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert but for me I just reinstalled from source together with the necessary packs and it worked.

```
sudo apt-get remove wifiphisher
sudo apt-get install -y python3-setuptools libnl-3-dev libnl-genl-3-dev libssl-dev
sudo apt-get update
git clone https://github.com/wifiphisher/wifiphisher.git
cd wifiphisher
sudo python3 setup.py install
```